# How to reduce number of queries for ManyToOne (jpa/hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa with a legacy database schema and having some problems with mapping one of the relationships. There are 2 entities in the database `buyer` and `employee`. One employee can have multiple buyers so its a `ManyToOne` relationship from buyer to employee.

This is how I have my jpa/hibernate entities configured:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUYER")
public class BuyerEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "BUYER")
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
   private EmployeeEntity employee;
....
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long id;
....
```

Basically, the `buyer` table has the foreign key `Employee_Id` pointing back to the primary key of the `employee` table.

When I do a lookup for buyers, jpa/hibernate first does a query to get all buyers and then for each buyer, it runs another query to retrieve the corresponding employee information. This is extremely inefficient because we can easily retrieve the employee information along with the buyer information by adding the employee table columns in the first query.

So instead of first doing a query that looks like this:

```
select buyer.id from buyer join employee ...
```

and then for each buyer do another query:

```
select employee.* from employee where employee.id = ?
```

if we can suggest jpa/hibernate to do a single query like this:

```
select buyer.*, employee.* from buyer join employee ...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to return a `List<Buyer>` with all their `Employee` references loaded in single query?

Comment: No - I would like to return a list of buyers with employee information populated in the buyer class

Comment: That's what I was asking :), see my answer.

Comment: :) sorry yeah didnt pay close attention to the comment

Comment: No worries, it happens, good luck with the answer & happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to issue the following query to accomplish your goal:

```
SELECT b FROM BuyerEntity b JOIN FETCH b.employee
```

You'll notice here I am applying a `JOIN FETCH` which tells Hibernate not only to join the `EmployeeEntity` table with the `BuyerEntity` table but to also fetch the data into the relation as part of a single query to the database.

If you want to use JPA Criteria API

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<BuyerEntity> query = cb.createQuery( BuyerEntity.class );
Root<BuyerEntity> root = query.from( BuyerEntity.class );

// specify join-fetch
root.fetch( "employee", JoinType.INNER );
query.select( root );

List<BuyerEntity> results = entityManager.createQuery( query ).getResultList();
```

Comment: The issue is that I am using JPA Criteria API to generate the queries and would prefer to not use HQL. This allows me to deal with more complex filters and simply would like to tell JPA/hibernate on how to retrieve the employee columns while doing a query on Buyers

Comment: See above, I edited the answer with JPA Criteria API being used as well.